# Should ViewModels have Count properties to simplify the View logic?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvvm

Which approach to ViewModels is better:
1. Just have an `ICollection<T>` in the ViewModel and access it's properties in views, which is pretty much what I'd do in ASP.NET Forms, like this:

```
public ICollection<Order> Orders {get; set;}
```

so that in the View I would do something like this

```
@if(Model.Orders.Count > 0){
```

or
2. Create a property for the `Count` of an ICollection so the View can simply reference that value directly.

```
public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
public int OrderCount { get { return Orders.Count ; } }
```

and then in the view

```
@if(Model.OrderCount > 0) {
```

or perhaps a boolean property `HasOrders` to further reduce the logic in the View?

**Edit**
I'm a bit surprised by the comments, I accept that this is subjective, but then so are questions about whether to use a string property for a date and everyone has to start learning somewhere.

Will I have numerous uses of the `OrderCount` property? The `if` and then a label to display the actual count. As such it will be used more frequently than say the customer email address yet I would be astonished if anyone suggested that

```
public string Email { get; set; }
```

was taking things too far.

To try to refocus the question a little; what I'm trying to determine is should the ViewModel provide simple properties for everything the view needs - so there is no need to reach down into the `Model.Orders` to access the Count. Should the View be kept pure and free from logic / 'programming'

Comment: 1st is preferable. 2nd is too much refactoring with no gain.

Comment: count properties, count methods, something is always better than nothing.

Comment: This is a hopelessly subjective question. I prefer adding count properties. Sundeep evidently does not. Could you refocus the question so it can be usefully answered?

Comment: There's no right answer to this highly subjective question, but I'd say that, unless you have numerous uses of the Count property, I wouldn't bother making a separate ViewModel property. So, I'd stick with (1).

Comment: Though this may be a subjective question, it is far from hopeless. There are cases when you might want to do one or the other. Generally you should go for the one that means you have to write less code, while still protecting consumers of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3.) Don't use a `Collection<T>` on a viewmodel, it's probably overkill. Instead, use T[]. Why? Because you shouldn't need `.Add`, `.Remove`, and other overhead methods offered by `ICollection` for an `IEnumerable` property in a viewmodel. In the end, if you are just using it as a DTO to pass data from a controller to a view, an array is perfectly fine. Nothing will have to be added to or removed from the enumerable during transit to and from the controller. Arrays are generally faster and leaner than `List`s and other `IEnumerable` implementations.

```
public Order[] Orders { get; set; }
```

Then, don't use `.Count`, use `.Length`. Having a separate property is usually overkill too IMO. Why? Because it just means you end up writing more code where you don't have to. Why add an `OrdersCount` property when you can just use `Orders.Length`?

```
@if (Model.Orders.Length > 0) {
```

If you are looking for something a little shorter, you can use the `.Any()` LINQ extension method (note you will have to have `using System.Linq;` when using this in a viewmodel class, but nothing extra should be needed to use it in a razor view):

```
@if (Model.Orders.Any()) { // returns true if Model.Orders.Length > 0
```

One possible exception to this guideline could be if `Orders` is not set, meaning it is `null`. In that case, your razor code above would throw a `NullReferenceException`. For this you could create a `HasOrders` property on the viewmodel to test against `null` and `.Length`. However a simpler solution could be to just initialize the property in a constructor:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Orders = new Order[0];
    }

    public Order[] Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Granted, with the above someone could still set the array to `null`, so it's your decision of whether to do this, or create a separate property to test against `null`, or just test against `null` in your razor code.

```
using System.Linq;

public class MyViewModel
{
    public Order[] Orders { get; set; }
    public bool HasOrders { get { return Orders != null && Orders.Any(); } }
}
```

...or...

```
@if (Model.Orders != null && Model.Orders.Any()) {
```

Any way you go, you end up with a little more code in either the consuming class or the consumed class. Use these factors to decide which approach means less code to write:

a.) Is it possible for the property to be `null`?

b.) How many collection properties are in the viewmodel?

c.) How many times do you have to test against either `null` or `.Length` in a razor view?

Comment: Some really useful things to keep in mind. Am I right in thinking that for b) the intention there is to keep the viewmodel quite lean, i.e. if there are lots of collections then there would be lots of extra properties. My impression of razor, from what I've read so far, is that there shouldn't be much / any logic testing going on in the view, which is why I started thinking about this question. So for c) I'm trying to avoid doing it at all... but am not clear whether that is something to strive for, or if its like getting 100% code coverage with tests, an ideal.

Comment: a.) Yes, keeping viewmodels as simple and lean as possible is a rewarding pattern to follow. b.) IMHO, `@if (Model.Orders != null && Model.Orders.Any()) {` is not a lot of code to have in a view, and it is perfectly reasonable, as long as it has its purpose. It is not "going overboard" with code logic in a razor view. c.) 100% code coverage, like many things you may encounter in a development project, is an unrealistic ideal. Sometimes you just have to make educated decisions and choose the most reasonable solution over the (impossible) perfect one.